# How to convert binary to integer in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

To put my question into perspective:

I have a PHP app, which stores IP's of users in a MySQL table.

The column type is `VARBINARY(16)`, and the app uses PHP's `inet_pton` to form a binary string.

That is the string has 4 bytes for a typical IP4 address.

How to retrieve these IPs from the table, displaying them in a human readable form?

My current solution is:

```
select INET_NTOA(CONV(HEX(ip),16,10)) from operation_ip;
```

Is there a more direct way to do that?

In particular is `CONV(HEX(x),16,10)` the easiest way to change 4 bytes into an integer (actually I believe it is not even an integer, but a string which looks like integer).

(I use `VARBINARY(16)`, as PHP's `inet_pton` can return 16-bytes for IPv6 addresses. AFAIK MySQL's `INET_NTOA` does not support IPv6, but at the moment this is not my biggest concern).

Comment: if you want a more direct form, don't convert the ip address to binary in order to store it on the database... that or sore both the address's string and the binary value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has nice built-in functions to handle this case:

```
INSERT INTO t(ip) VALUE (INET_ATON('1.2.3.4')); -- stores integer 16909060
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM t; -- returns string '1.2.3.4'
```

Or the PHP way:

```php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO t(ip) VALUE (' . ip2long('1.2.3.4') . '))'; 
// ip2long('1.2.3.4') = 16909060
// reverse conversion: long2ip(16909060) returns '1.2.3.4'
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution is to use a 4-byte integer as the type of the column. Unfortunatelly IPv6 requires 16-bytes, and MySQL does not have a support for such long integers, that's why I use VARBINARY(16). On the other hand, in some queries I am 100% sure that the result contains only rows with IPv4 adresses, and in such cases I'd like to convert VARBINARY(16) to (4-byte) INT quickly.

Comment: I disregarded the problem with IPv6 since you wrote "IPv6 (...) is not my biggest concern". As of v5.6.3, MySQL features exactly what you need: [`INET6_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) and [`INET6_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-ntoa). Until then, your approach is probably the best way to go. I woundn't store IPv4 and IPv6 in the same column, though, but in distinct columns.